# Changing modified date of a file in batch programming

Tags: batch-file

I have copied a file ABC.txt (modified date: 22/12/2012 15:26) from a directory to another and the modied date remaining same as of source file. But want to change it to current date.

Answer (score 0):

Internal commands in windows (assuming you are on windows) **Copy** , **Move**, **Xcopy** and **RoboCopy** preserve the modified date on a file. You may have to download a utility program for this purpose.
Happy New Year!

Comment: Happy New Year to you also. Thanks for your information. Can I able to open it in edit mode and then save the file? I think this may be a possible way to chage the modified date. As by manual process, I'm getting that. Please suggest on this.

Comment: please read this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/69581